# gRPC Client Never Receives Response Headers

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, grpc-web

I want to send information about the current client version from the server in all responses to the callers.

I want to have this information in the HTTP header. But I am not able to read the headers in the client.

I call the method WriteResponseHeaderAsync in the server method or interceptor (tried both). I see (Fiddler) that the header is in the response header.

But, I cannot read this header on the client or in the interceptor on the client. I tried everything.

My code in method:

```cs
var result = AuthorizationClient.LoginAsync(loginRequest);                 
var responseHeaders = await result.ResponseHeadersAsync;
```

ResponseHeaders is empty (responseHeaders.Count is 0) all time. I am able to use Trailers but the right place is HTTP header.

Is possible to read the response headers? Is possible to read the response headers in interceptors?

If yes, how?

I am using: C#, Grpc.AspNetCore.Web 2.51.0 (on server), Grpc.Net.Client.Web 2.51.0 (Client. Blazor WebAssembly)

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?